# C++ 11 correct way to pass a functional object by reference or pointer?

Tags: pointers, c++11, reference, functional-programming, pass-by-reference

I am trying to pass a random number generator around my program (I want to use a single one), however I cannot seem to find a way to pass it by reference.

Here is what I have tried thus far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

void test(const function<int()> arng0, const function<int()> & arng1, const function<int()> & arng2,
          const function<int()> frng0, const function<int()> & frng1, const function<int()> & frng2)
{
    cerr << "Auto - std::_bind size: " << sizeof(arng0) << endl;
    cerr << "Auto - std::_bind & size: " << sizeof(arng1) << endl;
    cerr << "Auto - std::_bind ref size: " << sizeof(arng2) << endl;

    cerr << "Functional size: " << sizeof(frng0) << endl;
    cerr << "Functional & size: " << sizeof(frng1) << endl;
    cerr << "Functional ref size: " << sizeof(frng2) << endl;
}

void main()
{
    default_random_engine e;
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 100);

    auto autoRng = bind(ref(dist), ref(e));
    function<int()> funcRng = bind(ref(dist), ref(e));

    test(autoRng, autoRng, ref(autoRng),
        funcRng, funcRng, ref(funcRng));

    system("Pause");
}
```

The output is 24 bytes for all of them. I know functional is a heavy wrapper, however passing by reference still should be 4 bytes?

**Answer:**

```
void testValue(const function<int()> arng0)
{
    arng0();
}

void testRef(const function<int()> & arng0)
{
    arng0();
}

    {// Pass by value
        auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            testValue(funcRng);
        }
        auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto total = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count();
        cerr << "TestVal time: " << total << endl;
    }
    {// Pass by ref
        auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            testRef(funcRng);
        }
        auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto total = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count();
        cerr << "TestRef time: " << total << endl;
    }
```

Results:
Test Value Time: 179 ms
Test Ref Time: 74 ms

Comment: Which compiler & version, which OS, which optimization flags are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got it right, passing by reference should be 4 bytes if you're on a 32 bit machine. `sizeof` is giving you the size of the thing being referenced, not the size of the reference. I don't think you need to use 'ref' at the callsite.

See `sizeof` documentation here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

Comment: Indeed if I check the size by using sizeof(ref(fp)) or sizeof(&fp) I get 4 bytes, however I was not certain.

Comment: Do you know a way I could test if it is passed by reference? __alignof() gives me 8 bytes.